# Get Formatted Date From Numbers bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm new to shell scripting, trying to figure out how to convert "20140910192311" to 2014/09/10 19:23:11 date format.

when I tried

> echo $(date --date "20140910192311" +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M:%S)

I got

date: invalid date `20140910192311'

Answer (score 2):

**substring extraction** using **character indexes** will do exactly what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash
day=20140910192311
echo "${day:0:4}/${day:4:2}/${day:6:2} ${day:8:2}:${day:10:2}:${day:12:2}"
```

**output:**

```
2014/09/10 19:23:11
```

**As a one-liner:**

```
day=20140910192311; echo "${day:0:4}/${day:4:2}/${day:6:2} ${day:8:2}:${day:10:2}:${day:12:2}"
```

That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 1):

`date` isn't that smart. You have to use the formats for GNU's `-d` option listed in the documentation. You'll probably have to parse it yourself.

```
if [[ 20140910192311 =~ ([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2}) ]]; then
    printf '%s-%s-%s %s:%s:%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}"
fi
```

Or probably better:

```
if [[ 20140910192311 =~ ([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2}) ]]; then
    LC_TIME=C date -d "$(printf '%s-%s-%s %s:%s:%s' "${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}")" '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
fi
```